# drag images onto a map

Tags: image, maps

I need to implement a feature where images can be geotagged. I want to drag and drop images(one or more images can be selected from the list) onto the map. Then the selected images should be geo tagged automatically to the point where they are dropped.

Can someone give me an idea on how to work on this.

Thanks

Comment: html, java,c#, php, what is your target?

Comment: is it possible to do this using html and javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with HTML and Javascript.
I would advice you to use the jquery libary.

What you do is render the map where you want to place an image(for this example new york city)

What you do is use jquery to make the image you want to drop of yourself at the statue of liberty 50% opacity and draggable.
Under the image you have an

in the middle of the image as a "pointer" which is not opaque.
People drag the "dot" under the image to the desired location.
When it's released you take the offset x and y, calculate that to the relative time x and y to find the geolocation and then store everything via ajax.

That's kinda the basis you'll have to work on to accomplish this.

It's a fun project though, but a bit timeconsuming.

Comment: how different is it if i'm using php ?

Comment: With php you cannot give dynamic user experience.
You can generate content on the fly, but a user that wants to drag an image doesn't want to refresh the page every pixel it's dragged because the drag event is lost everytime and you'd still need javascript.